# Drop down menu in Kivy Python

Tags: python, drop-down-menu, kivy

I had found a similar topic at stackoverflow but unluckily it didn't help me.

It's the first time I try to seriously program a GUI and I'm really getting mad.
I'm doing one step at a time, towards what I will finally need.

Now I'm trying to add a simple drop down menu in the top left corner of my widget, whose element should call a function whenever they are selected. I really looked for this in kivy documentation, and in this forum but I can't really solve this.

```
import multiprocessing
from mesh import MeshApp
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.button import Button
import os

MAINDIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

categories = {}

def getCategories():
    for dir in os.walk(MAINDIR):
        if len(dir[1]) == 0:
            filelist = set()
            for mesh in dir[2]:
                filelist.add(mesh.replace('_FRONT.png','').replace('_SIDE.png','').replace('_TOP.png',''))
            categories.update({dir[0]: filelist})

#class CategoriesList(DropDown):
#    pass

class MainWindow(Widget):
    def __init__(self):
        #self.categorieslist = CategoriesList()

        categories_list = DropDown()
        for i in categories.keys():
            btn = Button(text=i.replace(MAINDIR, ''), size_hint_y=None, height=30)
            btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: categories_list.select(btn.text))
            categories_list.add_widget(btn)

        mainbutton = Button(text='Choose directory', size_hint=(1, 1))
        mainbutton.bind(on_release=categories_list.open)
        categories_list.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(mainbutton, 'text', x))

        #and now???

class RenderApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.launchMeshApp()
        return MainWindow()

    def launchMeshApp(self):
        app = MeshApp()
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=app.run)
        p.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    getCategories()
    RenderApp().run()
```

And:

```
#:kivy 1.9.1

<MainWindow>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.6, 0.6, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 0, 0, 0.5
        Rectangle:
            pos: 0, self.height * 5 / 6 - 1
            size: self.width, 2
```

I've created the dropdown as seen in the docs and in several other forum. But I need to place it in the top left corner, and I never found, or understood, the way to do this. Moreover I didn't get how to make them call a function with a parameter whenever they are clicked.

Thank you very much

EDIT: I don't know why but the first line with "Hi all" is automatically deleted

Comment: An example that is reproducible would be quite nice. People here don't have `MeshApp` and other special things and most likely aren't willing to clone a repo if you'd provide a link to a complete project. Small and reproducible is a key to fast and correct answers. Also, there's kind of rule of "no hi", "no thanks", I think it was mentioned in [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). :P

Comment: To place in the top-left corner use a RelativeLayout with pos_hint: {'top': 1, 'left': 1} in the .kv file

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the dropdown menu, but I can answer the data one.

When you bind a callback, the first argument you receive will be which widget that is bound to the callback. So the idea is to create a class that uses Button as its base class, then you can define whatever extra information you need.

Here is a rough, non tested example based on the button API example:

```
class MyAwesomeButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyAwesomeButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.my_data = {} # enter your data here

def callback(instance):
    print('The button <%s> is being pressed' % instance.text)
    print instance.my_data

btn1 = MyAwesomeButton(text='Hello world 1')
btn1.bind(on_press=callback)
btn2 = MyAwesomeButton(text='Hello world 2')
btn2.bind(on_press=callback)
```